# Guess the recursion

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, recursion, mathematica, algebraic-combinatorics

[image]

I want to know if there is a package in Mathematica or maple that can give back some recursion given a list of polynomial in $f_{n}(h)$.
I want a recursion of the from 
$$ \sum_{k=0}^{N}a_{k}(h)f(n+k) =0  $$
where $a_{k}(h)$ is a rational function in $h$

For example I know there exists package RISC guess that where I give some list of rational numbers it can give me the recursion it satisfies. Here instead of rational number its polynomials.
The following gives the list of polynomials in $h$ the numbers denote the on the extreme left the index of the element in the my list. I have proved that there exist a $N$ such that 
$$ \sum_{k=0}^{N}a_{k}(h)f(n+k) =0  $$ this will hold still wondering for an example.

Comment: Where did these polynomials come from? Knowing their origin might help to find the recursion with or without special software

Comment: $f(n):=\sum_{k=1}^{n}s_{k,1^{n-k}}(1/h,1/h,0,0,0)\prod_{i=1}^{n}(1+(i-k)h)$ where $s_{k,1^{n-k}}(1/h,1/h,0,0,0)$ is the schur function in power sum symmetric basis where I replace $p_1=1/h$ and $p_2=1/h$ and rest $p_i=0$.